# i can't find the design viewer option in my visual studio community

Tags: visual-studio, design-view

when I create a new project the first time I can see the Design viewer option, but when I close VS and reload the project the second time I can't see the design viewer anymore, I didn't find the solution please help!

Answer (score 0):

When you open VS you may see the code page. If you want to see the designer view, click in the menu *View* and *Designer*. You can also use the shortcut *SHIFT+F7*. But first make sure, you opened the file in the project explorer.